# JSP's iterating using jstl

Tags: jsp, liferay, jstl, el, scriptlet

In this code I get authorId for each author's name from `bookListArray` and show it for each book, using iterating element `aBook`. How can I refactor my code with no scriplets? How can I iterate my `bookListArray` in .java code?

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>
<liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${bookListArray}" />
<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="builder.model.Book" keyProperty="bookId" modelVar="aBook">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookName" name="book-Name" />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookDescription" name="description" />
   <% 
     Author bookAuthor = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthor(aBook.getAuthorId());        
   %>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text value="<%=bookAuthor.getAuthorName() %>" name="Author" />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp path="/html/actionBook.jsp" align="right" />
</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
<liferay-ui:search-iterator />
```

It's my author and book lists:

```
List<Book> bookList = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
List<Author> authorList = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthors(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);

request.setAttribute("bookListArray", bookList);
request.setAttribute("authorListArray", authorList);
```

if you want to look at my project you can do it here: https://github.com/AlBoldyrev/Library/blob/master/bundles/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/LibraryBook-portlet/WEB-INF/src/com/softwerke/BookAndAuthor.java

Comment: @Parkash I need your help! :P

Comment: Where is bookListArray, may include that code too

Comment: @B'bekShakya I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was not so easy. First of all, in my situation, I can only show data from database tables. Therefore, to solve this problem, we should create 2 new model classes to hold there important variables.

I understand, that it wasn't one-string-question, but Im a bit dissapointed that no one gives even any ideas, because for professional it is very easy.

So:

1. We should create new classes `AuthorModel` and `BookModel` (I'll omit all package and import info):

   ```
   public class AuthorModel {
   private Author author;
   private int count;

   public AuthorModel(Author author) {
       this.author = author;
       this.count = BookLocalServiceUtil.countByAuthor(author.getAuthorId());
   }

   public String getAuthorName() {
       return author.getAuthorName();
   }  

   public long getAuthorId() {
        return author.getAuthorId();
   }

   public int getCount() {
        return count;
   }
   }
   ```

--

```
public class BookModel {

private Book book;
private Author author;
private long authorId;

public BookModel(Book book) {
    this.book = book;
}

public String getBookName() {
    return book.getBookName();
}

public String getBookDescription() {
    return book.getBookDescription();
}

public String getAuthorName() throws PortalException, SystemException {
    this.authorId = book.getAuthorId();
    author = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthor(authorId);
    String authorName = author.getAuthorName();
    return authorName;
}

public long getBookId() {
    return book.getBookId();
}
}
```

2. After that, we should use this classes in our portlet class:

---

```
List<BookModel> bookModelList = ArrayUtil.getAllBooks();
List<AuthorModel> authorModelList = ArrayUtil.getAllAuthors();
request.setAttribute("bookModels", bookModelList);
request.setAttribute("authorModels", authorModelList);
```

---

3. And our getAllBooks()/getAllAuthors() methods:

---

```
public class ArrayUtil {

protected static List<AuthorModel> getAllAuthors() throws SystemException{
    List<AuthorModel> authors = new ArrayList<AuthorModel>();
    List<Author> authorList = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthors(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
    for (Author author : authorList) {
        authors.add(new AuthorModel(author));
    }
    return authors;
}

protected static List<BookModel> getAllBooks() throws SystemException{
    List<BookModel> books = new ArrayList<BookModel>();
    List<Book> bookList = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
    for (Book book: bookList) {
        books.add(new BookModel(book));
    }
    return books;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for to this is to retrieve the list in your controller and add it to the request as attributes.
Then you can iterate it with c:foreach:

Example:

Controller:

```
List<Author> authorList = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthors(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
request.setAttribute("authorModels", authorList);
```

JSP:

```
<c:foreach items="${authorList}" var="author">
     <c:out value="${author.attr1}"/>
     <c:out value="${author.attr2}"/>
</c:foreach>
```

Then you have to include something like this into your SearchContainer.